# powershell / merging .txt-files into csv adding date and filename

Tags: powershell, csv, merge, multiple-columns, addition

it's me again, as i mentioned yesterday i'm new to Powershell (now 3 days) and i hope you can help me again.

What I want:
I want to merge different txt-files into one csv-file
PLUS every line which is added should start with the actual date (yyyy-mm-dd) and the filename.

[Expectation_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM2R1.png)

[WhatIamActuallyGetting_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJpcS.png)

So what I've got so far:

```
New-Item Shoppinglist_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd_hhmm).csv -ItemType File
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt

$desiredColumns = 'Date','Filename','Substance','Information','Comment'

ForEach ($file in $txtFiles) {
$csv = Import-Csv -path $file -Delimiter "`t"
$outcsv=$csv | Select-Object $desiredColumns

#I Think the mistake is somewhere here, but i habe no idea to fix it. :(
Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {(Get-Date -format s)}}
Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Filename'; Expression = {(GetFileName)}}


$outcsv | Export-Csv Shoppinglist_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd_hhmm).csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Append 
}
```

I hope there is someone outside in the world who can help me. :)

Comment: Two things. One: You're showing us what you want, but not what you're actually getting. That would be helpful. Two: GetFileName is a .NET method, not a Powershell CmdLet so I'm pretty sure you can't use it the way you seem to be doing in the second Select-Object statement.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know about the 'what i'm actually getting'-thing, i'll edit it in a couple of seconds. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to use calculated properties, but are overthinking this a bit.
Also, `Get-ChildItem` returns FileInfo or DirectoryInfo objects. (unless you specify switch `-Name`, in that case it returns only the names of the items in the path).

These objects have useful properties, such as FullName, Name, LastWriteTime, etc.
Since you only want **files** returned, you can use the `-File` switch.

This assumes both input files have the exact same columns as in your example:

```
# the folder where the input files are and where the output csv file should be saved
$path     = 'D:\Test'
$today    = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date)
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.txt' -File

$csv = foreach ($file in $txtFiles) {
        Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName -Delimiter "`t" | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {$today}},
                      @{Name = 'Filename'; Expression = {$file.Name}}, *
}

$fileOut = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('Shoppinglist_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmm}.csv' -f (Get-Date))
$csv | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

This assumes both input files have at least the 3 desired columns: 'Substance','Information' and 'Comment'

```
# the folder where the input files are and where the output csv file should be saved
$path     = 'D:\Test'
$today    = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date)
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.txt' -File

$csv = foreach ($file in $txtFiles) {
        Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName -Delimiter "`t" | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {$today}},
                      @{Name = 'Filename'; Expression = {$file.Name}}, 
                      Substance, Information, Comment
}

$fileOut = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('Shoppinglist_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmm}.csv' -f (Get-Date))
$csv | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>If you are using a PowerShell version below 3.0, you cannot use the `-File` switch. Instead then use: `$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.txt' | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }`</sup>

Comment: Thank you Theo, this one solves my problem! Have a great day!! <3